# how can i plot harmonic pattern using plotly in candlestick series?

Tags: python, plotly, candlesticks

how can i plot harmonic pattern using plotly in candlestick series like the image below?
The pattern has 5 or points to get connected fully

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
            open=df['open'],
            high=df['high'],
            low=df['low'],
            close=df['close'])])
```

the code above describes the candlestick series where the pattern is to be added.how can i add harmonic pattern to it?

[image]

Comment: If you have harmonic pattern data, you can draw it with `go.Scattter(mode='lines',...)`.

Comment: how do i add line suppose the line to draw has pionts A,B,C,D,E (268,269,268.4.269,267) to scatter?

Comment: Try this: `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[A.datetime,B.datetime,C.datetime,D.datetime,E.datetime],y=[268,269,268.4.269,267],mode='lines',name='Harmonic pattern'))
`